# Php:Combine Id and value array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two comma delimited lists corresponding to the Ids and values of something returned by a query.   I can easily convert each into an array using explode.

My question is how can I convert the two lists into a set of hyperlinks that use one from each as follows:

```
Ids:  34,23,78
Values: red, blue, green

Links: <a href='get.php?id=34'>red</a> etc.
```

I can use:

```
$valuesarray =explode(',',$values);
foreach($valuesarray as $val) {
Echo ....$Val
}
```

But how do I get the Ids into the link?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use `array_combine` to combine them into one array:

```
$arr = array_combine(explode(",",$ids),explode(",",$values));
foreach($arr as $id=>$value) {
    ...
}
```

But there are other ways. Such as:

```
$idarray = explode(",",$ids); $valuesarray = explode(",",$values);
// option 1:
foreach($idarray as $k=>$id) {
    $value = $valuesarray[$k];
}
// option 2:
$length = count($idarray);
for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
    $id = $idsarray[$i]; $value = $valuesarray[$i];
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

using $key => $value in the for each loop will accomplish this.

```
foreach($valuesarray as $id => $val) {
echo '<a href="file.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $val . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: That will work if you use array_combine to make the id array the keys and the other the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume the count of items is always the same you can just do a regular for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($valuesarray); $i++) {
    echo "<a href='get.php?id=" . $idsarray[$i] . "'>" . $valuesarray[$i] . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map them into an array with "id's" as key and "values" as values, like this:

```
$id_array = explode(',', $ids);
$value_array = explode(',', $values);
$final_array = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($id_array); $i++) {
    $final_array[$id_array[$i]] = $value_array[$i];
}
```

Note that you may also want to verify that the number of id's matches the number of values before entering the loop.

Comment: array_combine will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = '33,22,55';
$values = 'red,yellow,blue';

$ids = explode(',', $ids);
$values = explode(',', $values);

foreach($ids as $key => $value){
    echo "<a href='get.php?id=$ids[$key]'>$values[$key]</a><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id_arr = explode(',',$ids);
$val_arr = explode(',',$values);
for($i = 0; $i < count($id_arr); $i++)
{
    echo '<a href="get.php?id='.$id_arr[$i].'">'.$val_arr[$i].'</a>';
}
```